Is く in 驚く here not just devoiced but completely removed?
Here is an imgur link to three short lines from Monogatari Second Season episode 4:

虎のことを知っていた程度のことで
そんな驚くことはないだろう
私に知らないことはないんだよ

Listening to this I cannot help but feel it is pronounced like:

おどろっことはない

This is distinctly different from something like 買ってきた where き gets devoiced. The [k] is still quite audible here.
I hear essentially no remnant of く acting if it was devoiced, at least not to the extent of きた. If I recall correctly devoicing can occur when い or う are between voiceless consonants. ろ and こ are both voiceless so that would work. But if anything I hear っ. Am I missing some sound of the く leftover?

I think I can hear it implied (clearly) (on my first time listening, but I was intently listening for the k sound but not that intently)...? I'm not a native, however.

I think I know what you mean, but I do also hear some kind of pause between ろ and こ, which doesn't happen in something like 行くか (devoiced but no added mora). So if a [k] is there it seems to be taking more "mora space" than く (not sure but she is speaking very fast so it'd be weird to have a random slowdown imo)

This is an example of 促音化 (gemination):

Removing the く when pronouncing 洗濯機(せんたくき)
NHK放送文化研究所:「洗濯機」はセンタクキ？ センタッキ？

While there are words like 学校 or 国交, where the geminated pronunciation has become the official spelling, there are also words like 旅客機 or 水族館, where the occurrence of gemination varies depending on the speaker.
I agree that she pronounced 驚く事 completely as おどろっこと rather than おどろくこと. I had thought that gemination never occurred across two completely independent words, but her way of speaking sounds completely natural to me. I think most native speakers wouldn't notice gemination has happened until it's clearly pointed out to them.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find any research regarding gemination between two independent words containing "k", and I have no idea how often it happens among the general public. However, I feel gemination is more common among male speakers, and it's relatively common before the question marker か (e.g., "そろそろ行くか → そろそろ行っか").
